# CakePHP confusion over ACL

Tags: cakephp, acl

On the CakePHP website it shows that you would create a users table and a groups table for users and user groups using ACL: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1544/Preparing-our-Application

However most other tutorials e.g. NetTuts shows creating three tables (in addition to the users table) to use ACL: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-cakephps-access-control-lists/

What is the difference between the two? Thanls

Answer (score 2):

if you are asking about the extra tables named **Acos,Aros and aros_acos**

In both tutorial we need to use these tables.In the cakephp.org. there is a section called [Initialize the Db Acl tables](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1546/Initialize-the-Db-Acl-tables) where they running a command to create those tables. where as in nettuts they showing us creating it manually.

Any way cakePHP need 5 tables to run the ACL perfectly.In that **Acos,Aros and aros_acos** are cakePHP defined tables and **Users and Groups** are user defined tables.

CakePHP is storing the User permissions as a Tree with Aros(Access Request Objects means users)  hasAndBeongsToMany relation with Acos (Access Control Objects means actions)

Comment: How come in the Cake tutorial it never mentions the three tables and in the NetTuts tutorial it never mentions that the groups table?

Comment: cakebook uses command line to bake it. so wheh the command `cake schema create DbAcl` it creates the needed tables. please go though the link which i provided. Nettuts didn't mentioned the Groups because in their sample app They are setting user wise permission only not the group wise.I think i didn't told Group is a must.I mentioned 5 tables for perfect ACL functionality